# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on List<Character>

Tags: java, string, list, exception, character

I'm trying to write a program that splits up a String into an ArrayList, but I keep getting `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: <length of string>`. Anyone got any ideas? (I have the ArrayList and List classes already imported)

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String test = "Hello, World!";
    int testLength = test.length();
    List<Character> testChars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= testLength; i++){
        testChars.add(test.charAt(i)
    }
    System.out.println(testChars);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception occurs when `i` reaches `testLength`, since the index starts from zero and ends at the length of the string minus 1.

Change

```
for(int i = 1; i <= testLength; i++){
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < testLength; i++){
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I also changed int i = 1; to int i = 0; because the first letter was being left out...

Answer (score 2):

The indices of the String characters go from `0` to `test.length()-1`.

Therefore the loop should be :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < testLength; i++){
```

Comment: This is because Java is zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are correct.
Remember that arrays (and so Strings) in Java are zero indexed, so you should begin from 0, otherwise you loose the first element. While the array begins from 0 then should be to testLength - 1.

if testLength is 10 then 0..9 is 10 so you should loop over 0 to 9

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= testLength -1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop needs to change.  start at 0 and the stopping condition could be either  i<=testLength-1 or simply i < testlength.